# Why 2 verbs in this sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The following is a part of CNN Student News dated on Oct 18, 2016;

"Hundreds of US troops are involved, though the Pentagon says they're not on the front line. And the forces ***that are can call*** in air support when they meet with tough resistance from the terrorist."

In the part of 'that are can call', why are there 2 verbs? Is it correct?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It looks like an error to me.

Comment: Same as "And the forces *that exist* are...". "that are" is not really meaningful; it just refers back to the *forces*. "that be" can also be used this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking down the to sentences

> Hundreds of US troops are involved, though the Pentagon says they're not on the front line
>   *many of the troops involved are not on the front line*
>
> And the forces that are can call in air support...
>   *and the ones that* ***are*** *(involved on the front line)* ***can call in*** *air support*...

The sentences are references first those troops not on the front line and those who are on the front line.  There must be more context *somewhere* about those not on the front line.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit word here, "The forces that are **there**, can call in air support.

So you see, the verbs "are" and "can" are not really in any sense "working together"